# How do I get the menus become fully independent

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, intel-edison

I have this project http://codepen.io/neuberfran/pen/LZEgEr

```
But when I click in second menu, change the first menu

How I fix this issue?
```

Comment: solved by Batuhan Çilingiroğlu

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <title>wHome automatização</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Controlando minha Janela</h1>
        </div>

        <form action="" class="formulario">
            <div class="radio">
                <h2>Lado Direito</h2>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Abrir">
                <label for="Abrir">Abrir</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Parar">
                <label for="Parar">Parar</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Fechar">
                <label for="Fechar">Fechar</label>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form action="" class="formulariob">
            <div class="radiob">
                <h3>Lado Esquerdo</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="test">
                <label for="test">Abrir</label> 

                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="test1">
                <label for="test1">Parar</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="test3">
                <label for="test3">Fechar</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

you have to change id's and labels for second menu